# Missing positional Argument

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random
import os

path = os.getcwd()

bg = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/space.jpg'))

images = [
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R1.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R2.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R3.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R4.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R5.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R6.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R7.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R8.png'),
    pygame.image.load(f'{path}/R9.png')
]

win_width = 500
win_height = 600

win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))

class Spacemen(object):
    def __init__(self, y, velocity):
        self.y = y
        self.velocity = 5
        self.walk_count = 1
        self.gravity = True
        self.inverted_gravity = False
        self.x = 1

    def move(self):
        if self.gravity and not self.inverted_gravity:
            self.y += self.velocity
        if not self.gravity and self.inverted_gravity:
            self.y -= self.velocity

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.x == 10:
            self.x = 1
        if self.gravity and not self.inverted_gravity:
            img = images[self.x]
        elif not self.gravity and self.inverted_gravity:
            img = pygame.transform.flip(images[self.x])
        self.x += 1

        win.blit(img, (256, self.y))

def game_window():
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    Spacemen.draw(win)
    win.update

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    man = Spacemen(256, 5)

    running = True

    while running:

        pygame.time.delay(100)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                run = False

        man.move()

        game_window()

main()
```

When I run this it says that I am missing one positional error, missing "win" on line 54.

I do not know what is wrong because when I did something similar on a different project it worked perfectly. When I supply (win, win) another error pops up saying:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

`draw` is a [Method Object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). You have to pass an [Instance Object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class `Spaceman` to the function `game_window` and to invoke the method `draw` on the instance (`man`).

```py
def game_window(man):
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Pass the instance `man` of the class `Spacemen` to the function `game_window`:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    man = Spacemen(256, 5)

    running = True
    while running:

        # [...]

        game_window(man) # <-----
```

---

The the display is updated by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip). `win.update` makes no sense at all. A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) has no instance object `update` and for a call statement, the parentheses are missing.

<s>`win.update`</s>

```py
pygame.display.update()
```